# Where is the configuration file of Radiant CMS located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

I was asked to see if can migrate an old  website built with Radiant CMS to Wordpress. Problem is I haven't work with Ruby or any Ruby frameworks. I was given an FTP access to the site but there are a lot of files and its very confusing. What I want to know is the filename and location of the configuration file similar to wp-config in Wordpress? I want to examine the data structure so I can get an idea of how the website works.

Answer (score 0):

Radiant does not have that, the config is stored in the database.
Do you have an account for the backend (/admin)?

Generally speaking, the frontend exists entirely in the database; layout(s), snippets and pages which all can be updated through the backend. Stylesheets and javascripts may be static files in /public or may also be in the database; see if under the 'Design' tab you also have 'Javascripts' and 'Stylesheets'.

Comment: Oh, if you're looking for the database credentials, you can find those in config/database.yml